# Printer HP LaserJet P1005 does not work

Tags: printing

I plug in the printer, the system recognizes it, but when I try to print something nothing happens.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: during the installation process I need to enter my root password and I am prompted that the password is incorrect even though I am sure it is correct one. So I am stuck here at the moment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This helped :

```
sudo hp-setup -i
```